# Convert non fixed key json to csv file in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm new to Python and have a JSON file which I need to convert to csv file.

**JSON file:**

```
    {
     "id1":{
         "subid1":{"A":1,"B":2,"C":3},
         "subid2":{"A":5,"D":5,"F":7},
         "subid3":{"L":5,"Z":5,"P":7}
      },
     "id2":{
         "subid1":{"G":1,"O":9,"C":3},
         "subid2":{"A":5,"V":15,"F":0},
         "subid3":{"L":5,"H":2,"N":7}
      }
    }
```

The initial keys - id1, id2, etc are all unique for each Json object, and `subid1, subid2 and subid3` remain same in all the Json objects. However the inside json object changes as can be seen. It's not limited from  A to Z, but can be AA, XXSC, etc.

**Required CSV Format:**

```
primaryId, subId, letterID, number
id1, subid1, A, 1
id1, subid1, B, 2
id1, subid1, C, 3
id1, subid2, A, 5
.
.
id2, subid1, O, 9
id2, subid1, C, 3
.
.
id2, subid3, N, 7
```

Can you help me with it?

Comment: Can someone help me is not a question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you run into errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each dict with some nested loops.

```
def tocsv(json):
    for col1, data in json.items():
        for col2, data2 in data.items():
            for col3, col4 in data2.items():
                print(",".join([col1, col2, col3, str(col4)]))
```